# Sub-exponential Norm of Normal Distribution

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normal-distribution, expected-value, orlicz-spaces

Let $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$. Define the sub-exponential norm as follows for a random variable $Z$:
$$ \|Z\|_{\psi_1} := \inf \left\{k>0 \vert \mathbb{E}\left[\exp \frac{|Z|}{k}\right] \leq 2\right\}. $$

I would like to explicitly compute this norm for $X$. I have done this for the sub-gaussian norm by simply computing the expectation, which is monotonically increasing, and setting it equal to $2$, but this approach doesn't really work here because I can't seem to get a useable result for the integral. I think the norm should still be of the form $C\sigma$ for a positive constant $C$ (or at least something similar), but I can't seem to figure out how it looks exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think there is an exact way to calculate the norm. If you evaluate the integral you will get something that contains an error function that you have to set equal to $2$ to get the norm.

Comment: Yes that is the problem I ran into. I was wondering if perhaps one can cleverly relate it to the sub-gaussian norm or use some trick to avoid directly evaluating the expectation...

Comment: I guess an upper bound would be nice as well if it is reasonably tight

Comment: A trivial upper bound is $\frac{\|Z\|_{\psi_2}}{\sqrt{\ln 2}}$.

Comment: @GiorgosGiapitzakis How is this trivial, I think I am confused, but I don't immediately see why this is a bound...

Comment: It follows from the inequality $\|XY\|_{\psi_1} \leq \|X\|_{\psi_2}\|Y\|_{\psi_2}$ for $Y=1$.

Comment: Ah of course, thank you for the quick response!